# Why can't I uncompress a huge file without going out of memory in Linux while Windows can?

Tags: linux, windows, zip, 7z

I do have a 36GB .zip file to uncompress, which while being extracted will end up freezing the PC because of going oom (out of memory) with file-roller and the unzip command in a freshly installed Ubuntu (20.04).

**What I also tried**:

1. Extract the 36GB .zip in Windows with Windows Explorer and the official 7-Zip binary, which perfectly worked. Then compress the files again with 7-Zip using the .7z format on Windows, and made sure that the dictionary size to be so small that even a Raspberry Pi with 512MB of RAM would not run out of memory since an 8MB dictionary size means that only around 128MB of RAM are needed for decompression with LZMA1.

   While the extraction worked as expected in Windows in a old PC (2GB of RAM, minimum-sized pagefile.sys, Windows 10), it will still fails in Ubuntu on a 8GB of RAM PC that has 8GB of swap using file-roller and also the 7z command since I'm hitting the oom situation .

   I've also noticed that while things were going as planned in Ubuntu for some time (e.g only using the desired low amount of RAM, around 128MB), things will then suddenly go bad and RAM will quickly rises up to the max in less than 30 seconds then hit oom, while only 1GB of swap was able to be used out of 8GB.
2. Do the same .zip and .7z extractions on Debian, which still fails.

I also first hit that oom problem with `tracker-extract` skyrocketing RAM while extracting, which is `gnome-photo`'s indexer. So before facing the main issue here, removing any `tracker*` package is half-way solving things up.

**So the question is**: Why uncompressing a huge .zip or .7z in Linux doesn't work unlike Windows?

---

**Update 1:**

The problem is mostly solved (look for the comments, it's mostly a working directory issue using some `tmps` instead of the output folder, but I have to keep testing done to completely confirm everything.
To make it short: used a archiver that allows you to change the working folder, such as xarchiver or PeaZip.

Comment: Have you tried unpacking it with good old `unzip` instead of that "file-roller"?

Comment: Forgot to mention it, but yes.

Comment: It's the amount of virtual memory, not RAM, that counts. On UNIX and Linux, the size of virtual memory is roughly defined by the size of swap space plus RAM. One guess: Your Windows installation has larger "swap space" (or whatever it's called on Windows), or Windows implements virtual memory differently. You could try adding file swap in Linux to increase it. It's also possible that the Windows ZIP tool is more economical regarding memory usage.

Comment: On Windows, i manually set the lowest swap space (named "pagefile.sys) it allowed me to have, and I used both Windows Explorer extractor and 7zip to extract the .zip. On Linux, I don't quite understand why a file swap would help, since the already set swap partition wasn't even fully used (1GB at most) before hitting oom.

Comment: I don't see why unpacking a huge .zip file should go OOM, or even use much memory at all. I suspect that there's some memory leak/bug, maybe related to the zip64 format. But this is simply conjecturing. Try with `unzip -p huge_file.zip >/dev/null` ("extract to stdout") and see if it still OOMs. This may at least help narrow down the case.

Comment: Are you trying to unpack into some `tmpfs` directory? That might exhaust all RAM.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov : This might be spot on. I've then seen that archivers do use some kind of tmpfs (/tmp, /dev/shm, etc) as the working folder instead of the output one like it should be, and that mostly can't be changed. Apart from CLI archivers, Xarchiver is the only GUI one I've found to be able to choose that. It also looks like Windows mostly do not use a temp folder to unzip ( https://superuser.com/a/328545 ). As usual, you do often have the correct answer about the basic issues that we can hit on Linux (e.g oom and forcing the elitists to fix that ten years after the first reports) :)

Comment: Also adding more findings: `/var/run`, `/var/lock` and `/run` also are tmpfs,  so checking for them possibly getting filled might be worth it.

I also found that a very powerful archive manager (and also an excellent free 7Zip frontend, free .rar archiver and fully open-source) on Windows had recently been ported as a flatpak: `PeaZip`, which do allows to change the working directory.